# In Unity, how do I inject a named dependency into a constructor with other dependencies?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a service with some dependencies but 1 of them is a named dependency. So, want to config my Unity container to inject that.

I have some like this:

Register of types in Unity container:

```
container.RegisterType<IOtherService, Implementation>("SpecificImp);
container.RegisterType<IOtherService, OtherImplementation>("otherImp");

container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(
    new InjectionConstructor(                  // Explicitly specify a constructor
        new ResolvedParameter<IOtherService>("SpecificImp") // Resolve parameter of type IRepository using name "Client"
    )
);
```

Service:

```
puclic class Service : IService
{
     private read-only IOtherService _otherService;
     private read-only IworkContext _workContext;

    public Service(
        IOtherService otherService,
        IworkContext workContext)
    {
        _otherService = otherService;
        _workContext = workContext;
    }
}
```

But the compiler show me a error,

'Implementation' dont have a contrusctor with 'IOtherService' parameter.

So, who can i config mi container to inject correct implementation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying any constructor parameter explicitly, then you need to specify all parameters of that constructor

```
container.RegisterType<IService, Service>(
    new InjectionConstructor(                  // Explicitly specify a constructor
        new ResolvedParameter<IOtherService>("SpecificImp"), // Resolve parameter of type IRepository using name "Client"
    new ResolvedParameter<IworkContext>()
)
```